# How to avoid re-rendering of login component meanwhile app fetches data from firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

Every time I refresh the page, my react app renders the login component meanwhile it fetches the current status of signed in user. What is that is I am doing wrong over here, as redux store is supposed to be hold values even when the page is refreshed. But right now, even if the user is signed in, the app shows login component.

my app.js:

```
 import { doc, getDoc, setDoc } from "@firebase/firestore";
    import React, { useEffect } from "react";
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import { Route, Switch } from "react-router";
    import Login from "./components/Login";
    import Mainthread from "./components/Mainthread";
    import Notifications from "./screens/notifications";
    import Profile from "./screens/profile";
    import { auth, db } from "./services/Firebase";
    import { login, logout, selectUser } from 
    "./services/redux/userSlice";
    
    function App() {
      const user = useSelector(selectUser);
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      async function createDocument(id, data) {
        await setDoc(doc(db, "users", id), data);
      }
    
      async function checkDocument(id) {
        const docRef = doc(db, "users", id);
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
        if (docSnap.exists()) {
          console.log("your document exists with us...");
        } else {
          const data = { email: user?.email };
          createDocument(user?.uid, data);
          console.log("your document is being created...");
        }
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        function unsubscribe() {
          auth.onAuthStateChanged(function (authUser) {
            if (authUser) {
              dispatch(
                login({
                  uid: authUser.uid,
                  email: authUser.email,
                })
              );
              checkDocument(user?.uid);
            } else {
              dispatch(logout());
              console.log("Logged Out!");
            }
          });
        }
        unsubscribe();
      }, [dispatch]);
    
      return (
        <>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/notifications">
              <Notifications />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/profile">
              <Profile />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">{user ? <Mainthread /> : <Login />}</Route>
          </Switch>
        </>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

and userSlice.js:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  userDetails: null,
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.userDetails = action.payload;
    },
    logout: (state,action) => {
      state.userDetails = null;
    },
  },
});

export const { login, logout } = userSlice.actions;
export const selectUser = (state) => state.user.userDetails;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example

Comment: It's a missing semi-colon on line 6 - my mind was able to read your code without even seeing it

Comment: I suppose that "as redux store is supposed to be hold values even when the page is refreshed" is wrong.. Refresh the page => redux store will initialize again, not persisting data